# How do I completly delete Ubuntu 12.04 (only OS installed)?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, format, delete

I thought based on the tech spec that my PC would handle Ubuntu, but it's slow. I want to get rid of it, and perhaps install Xubuntu.

How can I completely delete this OS (the only one installed)? I have no windows to use to "overwrite" it.

Comment: What are your computer specs?

Comment: Intel Pentium 4 CPU 2.66 GHZ, 512+512 MB of RAM

Answer (score 13):

Boot other distro/OS that you want to install on your desktop and when you're prompted to set up your partitions, delete all existing.

[image]

Now when you've deleted all partitions, create a new one for your new distro/OS and install it.

Answer (score 3):

Use another computer or Ubuntu 12.04 to download and burn the Xubuntu ISO to your USB/CD and boot from it. Select the option to completely erase the old OS when installing Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need windows to overwrite it; use the USB key you already have, or the one you're going to use to re-install from; the obvious thing to do is to download Xubuntu, create the new USB drive, and do as others have suggested; if you really want to clear the drive first, you could just open a terminal, `sudo -i` to become root, & use `fdisk` to remove all partitions from your hard disk - but it isn't necessary to do so.

Why is it so slow? Is there a driver problem? Often it's silly things like a sound driver, or insufficient memory, if you use tools like `top` & `free` to see what's happening you may save bother with the new OS as well. I would suggest you try to work it out if you can as hardware drivers may well remain the same after an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You know you can just add the Xubuntu packages to any existing Ubuntu? It's a meta-package available in `apt` or the Software Center or Synaptic...

I think `apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` will do it.

And for just the XFCE window manager, it's `apt-get install xfwm4`